# Can I run my code in ECMAScript3?

Tags: javascript

I want to test my code in ecmascript3, but my web browser supports ecmascript5 and I can't install an older web browser.

(Thanks for correcting my English!)

Comment: Why do you want to test ECMAScript 3? Do you need to support an older client? If so, which one?

Comment: Re: "I can't install older web browser": Can you install other sorts of tools, such as standalone JavaScript interpreters?

Comment: @rid I want to more understand in my javascript book about Object.

Comment: @Domino: You will better try to understand about ES5's Object. There are important new features.

Comment: @Bergi I want to see different between Ecmascript3 and Ecmascript5.(sorry in my writing in English)

Comment: @Domino, everything is backwards compatible. All ECMAScript 3 code will run on any ECMAScript 5 interpreter, so you can use your ECMAScript 5 browser to run the ECMAScript 3 code in your book, and it should run exactly as intended. If you want to see how the old object worked, simply don't use any of the new features.

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 5 is a superset of ECMAScript 3. Everything that you can learn from your "old" book can be used in modern browsers, too.

---

In the comments you ask a different question … Read about the new features in ECMAScript 5 here: http://markcaudill.com/2009/04/javascript-new-features-ecma5/

---

If you are only interested in the changes to `Object`, read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

JavaScript 1.8.5 is a superset of ECMAScript 5. (You should notice that JavaScript is a proprietary language used Mozilla products. E.g. `Object.__parent__` is not part of the ECMAScript standard.)

Comment: I want to see different between Ecmascript5 and Ecmascript3 about Object.(sorry in my writing in English)

Comment: @Domino you're welcome! You might be interested in the actual standards text as well: http://es5.github.com/#x8.6